# Scala: Directory layout for test classes

Tags: scala, unit-testing

Based on Maven and sbt, the convention for layout of Scala test classes is under src/test/scala.  Under that directory, what is the proper convention for test classes?

Specifically:

1. Should the tests' dirs match the dirs structure of the classes they are testing?
2. Should unit tests and integration tests be put into separate dirs?  If so, how does that fit with #1?
3. Where do test helpers and test bases classes go? Code which is not a test but supports tests?
4. What about packages for all of these?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should think about what is good for you and helps your project rather than best practice.

My 5 cents:

1. A good thing about matching structure (packages) is that you can make internal stuff package private but still test them. Scala does not require you to match directory structure with package structure but a good thing doing that is that it is easy to find your way around the codebase.
2. I think that depends on your project, are the integration tests slow to run/mapped to a separate test run, or maybe slow to compile and you do not always want to compile them when you run the unit tests, then it could be an idea to even have a separate source root for them, but you could also use your test library´s tagging/category support and have them mixed or use a naming standard for the test cases (NnnnnSpec vs NnnnnIntegrationSpec for example)
3. Along with the test classes but named differently, possibly under a separate package that is easily recognized as test support/utilities
4. See #1 and #3